# How to trace for all functions in an Erlang module except for one?

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching, trace

I wanted to trace for all functions in an erlang module, with `dbg:tpl`, but one of the internal functions took up 95% of the trace file. I then wanted to exclude only that single function and found that it was not as easy as I thought it would be.

**I know there are great pattern matching possibilities for arguments when tracing.**

- Is there a similar possibility to apply pattern matching for functions?

  `eg.: {'=/=', '$2', function_name}`

I am open for outside-the-box solutions as well!

Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be achieved as one statement with a list comprehension:

```
[dbg:tpl(Mod, F, []) || {F, _Ar} <- Mod:module_info(functions), not lists:member(F, DontTrace)].
```

Where `Mod` is the module you want to trace on, and `DontTrace` is a list of functions names that should not be traced on.

Comment: The final solution was: >>> [dbg:ctp(Mod, F, []) || F <- [dontTrace1,dontTrace2,dontTrace3]]. <<< I used this since I wanted to know immediately if I messed up a functions name.

Comment: Ah, I've updated the code to actually trace instead of clear. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
dbg:tpl(mod,[]).
dbg:ctpl(mod,notthisfunction).
```

Haven't tested this but shouldn't this do the trick? Don't know of a way to do it in one line.

Comment: This definitely is promising!

Still not a one liner, but the shortest version I have yet.

Problem is if I want to disable tracing on 5 functions, I will have to use dbg:ctpl 5 times...